# Error when calling Rabbitmq consumer from command line

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to setup a simple AMQP publisher/consumer using Symfony2.2 with [RabbitMq bundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle), I am following the documentation on the bundle page

The publisher works fine, I can see my messages on the web manager of rabbitMq.
When I try to run a consumer using the command

```
php app/console rabbitmq:consumer my.api
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method My\ApiBundle\Service\ConsumerService::setRoutingKey() in /***/vendor/oldsound/rabbitmq-bundle/OldSound/RabbitMqBundle/Command/BaseConsumerCommand.php on line 91
```

My setup:

**confi.yml**

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        my.api:
        host:      %amqp_host%
        port:      %amqp_port%
        user:      %amqp_user%
        password:  %amqp_password%
        vhost:     %amqp_vhost%
    producers:
        my.api:
            connection: my.api
            exchange_options: {name: 'my.api', type: fanout}
    consumers:
        my.api:
            connection: my.api
            exchange_options: {name: 'my.api', type: fanout}
            queue_options:    {name: 'my.api'}
            callback:         my.api
```

**My\ApiBundle\Service\ConsumerService.php**

```
namespace My\ApiBundle\Service;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;

class ConsumerService implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function execute(\PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My\ApiBundle\Resources\config\services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="old_sound_rabbit_mq.my.api_consumer" class="My\ApiBundle\Service\ConsumerService"></service>
    </services>
</container>
```

My question is: what is wrong with my config or my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to register your handler as a service - removing the My\ApiBundle\Resources\config\services.xml definition completely should solve the problem.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I remove the service definition from config I get error "You have requested a non-existent service"

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue. The problem was that I forgot to include the RabbitMQ config file.

You can compare your solution with my working repository:

https://github.com/petrvacha/rebbitmq-basic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the documentation is correct.. but I found a workaround by extending from `OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\BaseConsumer`

So my code looks like:

```
namespace My\ApiBundle\Service;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\BaseConsumer;

class ConsumerService extends BaseConsumer
{

}
```